# Dashboard platform with custom widgets and mobile app

Tags: cross-platform, mobile, dashboard, widget, multi-user

I'm looking for a **web-based dashboard platform** with support for custom widgets. I need to "export" it like a white labelled mobile app afterwards with minimal effort. Dashboard and exported app should support multi-user access especially for external customers with limited permissions.

I found these 3:

http://www.datazen.com/

https://buildfire.com/

birst.com (low reputation for the 3rd link)

but all of them are not robust enough. The first one is linked to their own database. The second one look like just mobile app building tool. The third one looks the most promising but not for the customers, but internal analyst only.

I'm trying to avoid to build my own solution in all cases.

Thank you for recommendations in advance.

Comment: Please explain in details what kind of application you want to build. Will your application need to work offline? What widgets will you need? Will it need to save data locally? Will it need access to GPS/camera/etc?

Comment: What is wrong with buildfire exactly?

Comment: When you say "*multi-user access*" do you mean that each user can access with their own mobile device? Or will a single mobile device be shared by several users?

Comment: 1. it does not have to work offilne in any cases, but should be available under minimal interaction allowed
2. it is just for ios/android, not for dashboard which can be accessed with desktop web browser
3. with their own mobile device and with their own account

Comment: Please edit your question and add all requirements. Comments get deleted.